# Number of Independent Sets in a tree

Tags: algorithms, trees

(I've been stuck on this homework assignment for far too long)

I need to find the number of independent sets in a tree.

For example, say the set of nodes in a tree is {A, B, C, D, E}. B and C are children of A and D, E are children of B. This tree has 14 independent sets.

I assume that the algorithm will be recursive and I think that I should make each level of a tree into a linked list, so B->C and D->E, but more than that I'm stumped.

Would grealy appreciate help.

Comment: Consider constructing the tree step by step, starting with the trivial 1-node tree and repeatedly bringing in children of present vertices in an arbitrary order. Can you come up with a recursive formula for the number of independent sets at any given point in time? If so, transform this analysis into a dynamic programming solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Compute recursively the number of independent sets (a) containing the root, (b) not containing the root.